# Embedded derby multiple connections issue

Tags: database, derby

My web application(to be deployed on tomcat) required an embedded database to store temporary user data for faster retrieval. I chose Apache Embedded Derby because it is easy to embed in a web application and is a pure Java DB.

I also implemented connection pooling to retrieve connections. I am facing two critical issues(show stopper) here. First, My application cannot have more than two active connections at a time. So, my application just hangs up.

Second, i keep getting another application has already booted the database. I suspect it happens when one connection is already active and i try fetching another connection from pool.

I have read that embedded derby db can have only one connection at a time then how does it supports connection pooling through [EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource](http://db.apache.org/derby/javadoc/publishedapi/jdbc3/org/apache/derby/jdbc/EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource.html).

Should i now run db in network derby or embedded server derby mode? I don't like the idea of network mode, because i need faster retrieval. I would rather use MySQL then. And if I run db in embedded server db mode, will it support connection pooling and atleast 50 concurrent connections
**or** 
Should i just replace derby with other embedded database like H2 or HSQL database as i have read that derby is for training purpose only and should not be used in production environment? Kindly assist

Comment: Derby is certainly deployed in many production environments, and Derby certainly supports many simultaneous connections. It's not clear exactly what question you're asking, nor what sort of help you desire. The network server configuration is very fast; I certainly found it plenty fast enough for my usage.

Comment: I m running derby in embedded mode. My question is whether it supports concurrent connections in embedded mode. For one connection active, another getConnection() method causes the following error: "Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database".

Comment: I have two options now: Either I switch to network/server mode or embedded server mode or to a new database altogether. My primary requirement is connection pooling so as to support concurrent connections and faster retrieval(embedded db) such that i don't query on network. Please assist

Comment: The two getConnection() calls must be from the same JVM, and, more specifically, from the same classloader in the same JVM. This is a common confusion when building web applications, because app servers often use separate classloaders for each web app. Why don't you try using the Network Server for a while until you're more comfortable using Derby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented connection pooling with Apache commons dbcp and it works perfectly fine and that too in embedded mode.